# PHP-Ajax data migration issue

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Not able to figure out why my ajax code is not sending the data to the php file. have tried many things but it doesn't seem to work.
can anybody help me out here please.
My html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>ABC Fashion</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script type = "text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
 alert((this).id);
 var id=(this).id;
 var params ={id : (this).id};
$.post("code.php", params);
  alert(1);
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main_container">
<div class="center_content"  align="center">
  <div class="center_title_bar"  align="center">Latest Products</div>
  <div class="prod_box">
    <div class="top_prod_box"></div>
    <div class="center_prod_box">
      <div class="product_title"><a href="details.html">Levi's Men's Cotton T-Shirt</a></div>
      <div class="product_img"><a href="details.html"><img src="images/T1.jpg" name="tshirt" alt="" border="0" id="T1"/></a></div>
       <div class="product_img"><button id="d1" onclick="">Dislike</button></div>
       <div class="prod_price"><span class="reduce">350$</span> <span class="price">270$</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom_prod_box"></div>
    <div class="prod_details_tab"> <a href="#" title="header=[Add to cart] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/cart.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="#" title="header=[Specials] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/favs.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="#" title="header=[Gifts] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/favorites.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="details.html" class="prod_details">details</a> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prod_box">
    <div class="top_prod_box"></div>
    <div class="center_prod_box">
      <div class="product_title"><a href="details.html">UB Stylish T-shirt</a></div>
      <div class="product_img"><a href="details.html"><img src="images/T2.jpg" name="tshirt" alt="" border="0" id="T2"/></a></div>
       <div class="product_img"><div class="product_img"><button id="d2" onclick="">Dislike</button></div></div>
      <div class="prod_price"><span class="price">270$</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom_prod_box"></div>
    <div class="prod_details_tab"> <a href="#" title="header=[Add to cart] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/cart.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="#" title="header=[Specials] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/favs.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="#" title="header=[Gifts] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/favorites.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="details.html" class="prod_details">details</a> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prod_box">
    <div class="top_prod_box"></div>
    <div class="center_prod_box">
      <div class="product_title"><a href="details.html">Jacob n John T-Shirt</a></div>
      <div class="product_img"><a href="details.html"><img src="images/T3.jpg" name="tshirt" alt="" border="0" id="T3"/></a></div>
       <div class="product_img"><div class="product_img"><button id="d3" onclick="">Dislike</button></div></div>
      <div class="prod_price"><span class="reduce">350$</span> <span class="price">270$</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom_prod_box"></div>
    <div class="prod_details_tab"> <a href="#" title="header=[Add to cart] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/cart.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="#" title="header=[Specials] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/favs.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="#" title="header=[Gifts] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/favorites.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="details.html" class="prod_details">details</a> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prod_box">
    <div class="top_prod_box"></div>
    <div class="center_prod_box">
      <div class="product_title"><a href="details.html">Levi's Men's Cotton T-Shirt</a></div>
      <div class="product_img"><a href="details.html"><img src="images/T4.jpg" alt="" border="0" /></a></div>
       <div class="product_img"><div class="product_img"><button id="d4" onclick="">Dislike</button></div></div>
      <div class="prod_price"><span class="reduce">350$</span> <span class="price">270$</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom_prod_box"></div>
    <div class="prod_details_tab"> <a href="#" title="header=[Add to cart] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/cart.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="#" title="header=[Specials] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/favs.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="#" title="header=[Gifts] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/favorites.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="details.html" class="prod_details">details</a> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prod_box">
    <div class="top_prod_box"></div>
    <div class="center_prod_box">
      <div class="product_title"><a href="details.html">UB Stylish T-shirt</a></div>
      <div class="product_img"><a href="details.html"><img src="images/T5.jpg" alt="" border="0" /></a></div>
       <div class="product_img"><div class="product_img"><button id="d5" onclick="">Dislike</button></div></div>
      <div class="prod_price"><span class="price">270$</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom_prod_box"></div>
    <div class="prod_details_tab"> <a href="#" title="header=[Add to cart] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/cart.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="#" title="header=[Specials] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/favs.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="#" title="header=[Gifts] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/favorites.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="details.html" class="prod_details">details</a> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prod_box">
    <div class="top_prod_box"></div>
    <div class="center_prod_box">
      <div class="product_title"><a href="details.html">Jacob n John T-Shirt</a></div>
      <div class="product_img"><a href="details.html"><img src="images/T6.jpg" alt="" border="0" /></a></div>
       <div class="product_img"><div class="product_img"><button id="d6" onclick="">Dislike</button></div></div>
      <div class="prod_price"><span class="reduce">350$</span> <span class="price">270$</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom_prod_box"></div>
    <div class="prod_details_tab"> <a href="#" title="header=[Add to cart] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/cart.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="#" title="header=[Specials] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/favs.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="#" title="header=[Gifts] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/favorites.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="details.html" class="prod_details">details</a> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prod_box">
    <div class="top_prod_box"></div>
    <div class="center_prod_box">
      <div class="product_title"><a href="details.html">Levi's Men's Cotton T-Shirt</a></div>
      <div class="product_img"><a href="details.html"><img src="images/T7.jpg" alt="" border="0" /></a></div>
       <div class="product_img"><div class="product_img"><button id="d7" onclick="">Dislike</button></div></div>
      <div class="prod_price"><span class="reduce">350$</span> <span class="price">270$</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom_prod_box"></div>
    <div class="prod_details_tab"> <a href="#" title="header=[Add to cart] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/cart.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="#" title="header=[Specials] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/favs.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="#" title="header=[Gifts] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/favorites.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="details.html" class="prod_details">details</a> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prod_box">
    <div class="top_prod_box"></div>
    <div class="center_prod_box">
      <div class="product_title"><a href="details.html">UB Stylish T-shirt</a></div>
      <div class="product_img"><a href="details.html"><img src="images/T8.jpg" alt="" border="0" /></a></div>
       <div class="product_img"><div class="product_img"><button id="d8" onclick="">Dislike</button></div></div>
      <div class="prod_price"><span class="price">270$</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom_prod_box"></div>
    <div class="prod_details_tab"> <a href="#" title="header=[Add to cart] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/cart.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="#" title="header=[Specials] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/favs.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="#" title="header=[Gifts] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/favorites.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="details.html" class="prod_details">details</a> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prod_box">
    <div class="top_prod_box"></div>
    <div class="center_prod_box">
      <div class="product_title"><a href="details.html">Jacob n John T-Shirt</a></div>
      <div class="product_img"><a href="details.html"><img src="images/T9.jpg" alt="" border="0" /></a></div>
       <div class="product_img"><div class="product_img"><button id="d9" onclick="">Dislike</button></div></div>
      <div class="prod_price"><span class="reduce">350$</span> <span class="price">270$</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom_prod_box"></div>
    <div class="prod_details_tab"> <a href="#" title="header=[Add to cart] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/cart.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="#" title="header=[Specials] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/favs.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="#" title="header=[Gifts] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/favorites.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="details.html" class="prod_details">details</a> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prod_box">
    <div class="top_prod_box"></div>
    <div class="center_prod_box">
      <div class="product_title"><a href="details.html">Levi's Men's Cotton T-Shirt</a></div>
      <div class="product_img"><a href="details.html"><img src="images/T10.jpg" alt="" border="0" /></a></div>
       <div class="product_img"><div class="product_img"><button id="d10" onclick="">Dislike</button></div></div>
      <div class="prod_price"><span class="reduce">350$</span> <span class="price">270$</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom_prod_box"></div>
    <div class="prod_details_tab"> <a href="#" title="header=[Add to cart] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/cart.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="#" title="header=[Specials] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/favs.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="#" title="header=[Gifts] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/favorites.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="details.html" class="prod_details">details</a> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prod_box">
    <div class="top_prod_box"></div>
    <div class="center_prod_box">
      <div class="product_title"><a href="details.html">UB Stylish T-shirt</a></div>
      <div class="product_img"><a href="details.html"><img src="images/T11.jpg" alt="" border="0" /></a></div>
       <div class="product_img"><div class="product_img"><button id="d11" onclick="">Dislike</button></div></div>
      <div class="prod_price"><span class="price">270$</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom_prod_box"></div>
    <div class="prod_details_tab"> <a href="#" title="header=[Add to cart] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/cart.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="#" title="header=[Specials] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/favs.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="#" title="header=[Gifts] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/favorites.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="details.html" class="prod_details">details</a> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="prod_box">
    <div class="top_prod_box"></div>
    <div class="center_prod_box">
      <div class="product_title"><a href="details.html">Jacob n John T-Shirt</a></div>
      <div class="product_img"><a href="details.html"><img src="images/T12.jpg" alt="" border="0" /></a></div>
       <div class="product_img"><div class="product_img"><button id="d12" onclick="">Dislike</button></div></div>
      <div class="prod_price"><span class="reduce">350$</span> <span class="price">270$</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom_prod_box"></div>
    <div class="prod_details_tab"> <a href="#" title="header=[Add to cart] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/cart.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="#" title="header=[Specials] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/favs.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="#" title="header=[Gifts] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]"><img src="images/favorites.gif" alt="" border="0" class="left_bt" /></a> <a href="details.html" class="prod_details">details</a> </div>
  </div> 
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

and my php code is as follows:

```
 <?php


$servername = "localhost:3306";
$username = "admin";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "testdb";


$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_error($conn));
} 

 $num= (int)$_POST["params"];
 $str = $num;
 $tempid = substr_replace($str,"T",0);
 echo $str;
$sql = "INSERT INTO `test` (`disliked`) VALUES ('$num')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} 
else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?  Do either of your alerts popup with the expected values?

Comment: try to use var params ={"id" : id}; and in your php file the $num will be not getted you should use $num = $_POST['id'] and if you could please tell us what kind of error you get it will be great try to check you element inspector and debug the request parameter to see if they are token or not

Comment: yes they do.
but when i access the value on the php page i get a null.
don't know whats wrong here.
Does this method of getting data works only with a form as i am not using a form on my html page??

Comment: @RmidiAyoub not working
i am not getting any error the code is working fine but i am not able to get the value of id in my php file, it seems the data is not getting sent by the ajax code.

Comment: If you add this code - echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST["id"]); in your PHP file, you'll get the clicked ID. I am just wondering what exactly you are trying to achieve and what do you mean with data is not getting sent by the ajax code. If you check the parameters in console, you'll get clicked id. As mentioned above, you should get the id with $_POST['id'].

Answer (score 0):

You have in your code `var params ={id : (this).id};` which is wrong. Should be `var params ={id : $(this)[0].id};` (And change all instances of `(this).id` to `$(this)[0].id`)

And you're passing the `id` parameter, so on the server side, change `$_POST["params"];` to `$_POST["id"];`

```
$num= $_POST["params"]; // REMOVE(int) casting, you're doing it on the next line
```

Comment: Nope no changes
still getting a null on my php page

Comment: @navs89 I found additional problem with your code, see updated answer

Comment: i changed that when you suggested var params ={id : (this).id}; but that also doesn't seem to work

Comment: But it's not what I have suggested, my suggestion was `var params ={id : $(this)[0].id};`